# R Alteryx Output Results being trimmed

Tags: r, alteryx

Hope all is well.

I need some help.

I am very new to Alteryx and i am trying to query an API endpoint. I initally started off with the download tool, but due to corporate proxy settings i encountered issues and got pushed into Using R programming language (Which is even Newer to me)

Playing around i was able to set up the following R config in atleryx which calls an hard coded API and and it returns a Json string;

```
library (readr)
library (rjson)
urlfile="https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/fuzzycompletions?field=entity.legalName&q=hacker"

mydata<-read_tsv(url(urlfile))
write.Alteryx(mydata,nOutput = 1)
write.Alteryx(as.data.frame(mydata), 2)
```

Checking the logs i can see its returning Results (As shown below in picture)

[image: R Results]

Copying the Result set out it returns the followings ;

```
Info: R (1):   `{"data":[{"type":"fuzzycompletions","attributes":{"value":"NIE"},"relationships":{"lei-records":{"data":{"type":"lei-records","id":"529900NZ1T1N37O7I882"},"links":{"related":"https:\/\/api.gleif.org\/api\/v1\/lei-records\/529900NZ1T1N37O7I882"}}}},{"type":"fuzzycompletions","attributes":{"value":"NIKO"},"relationships":{"lei-records":{"data":{"type":"lei-records","id":"969500K0WJRAUS2FNW97"},"links":{"related":"https:\/\/api.gleif.org\/api\/v1\/lei-records\/969500K0WJRAUS2FNW97"}}}},{"type":"fuzzycompletions","attributes":{"value":"Niko"},"relationships":{"lei-records":{"data":{"type":"lei-records","id":"549300IYED05N6540X13"},"links":{"related":"https:\/\/api.gleif.org\/api\/v1\/lei-records\/549300IYED05N6540X13"}}}},{"type":"fuzzycompletions","attributes":{"value":"NINE"},"relationships":{"lei-records":{"data":{"type":"lei-records","id":"969500RT78M2KN3C1H75"},"links":{"related":"https:\/\/api.gleif.org\/api\/v1\/lei-records\/969500RT78M2KN3C1H75"}}}},{"type":"fuzzycompletions","attributes":{"value":"NICEO"},"relationships":{"lei-records":{"data":{"type":"lei-records","id":"96950045BC9VZN8KOJ34"},"links":{"related":"https:\/\/api.gleif.org\/api\/v1\/lei-records\/96950045BC9VZN8KOJ34"}}}},{"type":"fuzzycompletions","attributes":{"value":"Nigen"},"relationships":{"lei-records":{"data":{"type":"lei-records","id":"8755000MUIAIQH0E6Q68"},"links":{"related":"https:\/\/api.gleif.org\/api\/v1\/lei-records\/8755000MUIAIQH0E6Q68"}}}},{"type":"fuzzycompletions","attributes":{"value":"NIKUS"},"relationships":{"lei-records":{"data":{"type":"lei-records","id":"969500F6A5XNU1JUUE76"},"links":{"related":"https:\/\/api.gleif.org\/api\/v1\/lei-records\/969500F6A5XNU1JUUE76"}}}},{"type":"fuzzycompletions","attributes":{"value":"NYKEI"},"relationships":{"lei-records":{"data":{"type":"lei-records","id":"549300HQCRJU2SEE0249"},"links":{"related":"https:\/\/api.gleif.org\/api\/v1\/lei-records\/549300HQCRJU2SEE0249"}}}},{"type":"fuzzycompletions","attributes":{"value":"NIJEDA"},"relationships":{"lei-records":{"data":{"type":"lei-records","id":"96950023YYQ81KATG570"},"links":{"related":"https:\/\/api.gleif.org\/api\/v1\/lei-records\/96950023YYQ81KATG570"}}}},{"type":"fuzzycompletions","attributes":{"value":"NiKaTo"},"relationships":{"lei-records":{"data":{"type":"lei-records","id":"875500F20Y5JQUDJGD81"},"links":{"related":"https:\/\/api.gleif.org\/api\/v1\/lei-records\/875500F20Y5JQUDJGD81"}}}}]}` = col_character()
```

I am trying to get this result set into an output file, so i can do some further analysis however its only returning the following ;

```
"{""data"":[{""type"":""fuzzycompletions"",""attributes"":{""value"":""NIE""},""relationships"":{""lei-records"":{""data"":{""type"":""lei-records"",""id"":""529900NZ1T1N37O7I882""},""links"":{""related"":""https:\/\/api.gleif.org\/api\/v1\/lei-records\/529900NZ1T1N37O7I882""}}}},{""type"""
```

I am probably doing something wrong, but i am hoping you can point me in the right direction

Looking forward to your assistance

Comment: Maybe stating the obvious here but do you have an output tool connected to the R tool (e.g. output data)? Also, can you post a screenshot of your workflow?

Comment: Try writing it to output anyway... what you see on screen is just a truncated view.